# Accessing Microphone in Android SDK

Tags: android

Is there any way to access the micro phone in a android phones similar to accessing the ***android.hardware.Camera***?. 
I know we can use **MediaRecorder** to record audio from android application into a file as shown in this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html) .

Let me explain what I want to do. I'm accessing Camera from android program to capture video and get each captured frame using Camera.Preview callback function. After decoding the frame I'll upload to say a streaming server (haven't tried practically yet :) ) These frames will contain only image information how can I get audio along with frames?

Can any one suggest me technique for implementing the above idea?

Comment: What you're trying to do does not sound like a good project for "a beginer for android dev". It sounds like a delightful project for a team of engineers. You can access the microphone via the `AudioRecord` class, but how you marry that up with your frames is up to you.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the AudioRecord pointer that's really helpful. Yeah I agree its not a beginner project :) I'm helping a friend in this project.

Answer (score 4):

yes here it is

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html